# Find the next number with all different digits, and no 0 or 2

Tags: c++, c++11

**Task**

Input - integer number (year)

Print one number - the next year, in which all digits are pairwise different, and there are no digits 2 and 0. If there will never be such a year, print `-1`.

**My solution** (correct)

Could you please recommend time / space complexity optimizations?

```
vector<char> toVec(int n) {
    vector<char> res;
    while (n > 0) {
        res.push_back((n % 10) + '0');
        n /= 10;
    }
    return res;
}

int main(){
    int year;
    cin >> year;
    for (int i = year + 1; i < pow(10, 8); ++i) {
        vector<char> v = toVec(i);
        if (find(begin(v), end(v), '2') == v.end() and
            find(begin(v), end(v), '0') == v.end()) {
            set<char> temp(v.begin(), v.end());
            if (v.size() == temp.size()) {
                cout << i;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << -1;
    
}
```

Comment: pow() is a floating-point function, and should generally avoid them when you can. More importantly, it gets called every iteration of the loop; you should probably precompute and  store the result in a variable and use that variable in the loop.

Comment: @Ilkhd gcc actually optimizes `i < pow(10, 8)` to the equivalent of `i < 100000000`, but I agree you shouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing some headers (`<vector>`, `<iostream>`, `<cmath>` and `<set>`), and also to be assuming the standard names are in the global namespace, rather than `std`.

After attempting to read from `std::cin`, it's important to ensure the read was successful before attempting to use the result.  (E.g. `if (!(std::cin >> year)) { std::cerr << "Input failure\n"; return EXIT_FAILURE; }`).

A linear search will be inefficient, especially as we may have to skip long runs containing the banned digits `0` and `2`.  It would be better to construct the result using the available digits than to consider and test every possible number.  The search is flawed anyway, since `std::pow(10, 8)` could be larger than the maximum `int`, leading to overflow (which is Undefined Behaviour).

Comment: On what kind of hardware is INT_MAX < 10^8 ? A mic microcontroller? ;-)

Agree about composing from digits.

Comment: `INT_MAX` must be at least 32767, which is significantly less than 10⁸; I wouldn't want to enumerate all platforms, but certainly 8-bit microcontrollers are likely to tend towards the smaller values.